# Что значит принимаемый float в setPivotX()?

Tags: android, анимация

Метод формирует на поверхности View точку, относительно которой будут применяться некоторые трансформации при анимировании. Но неизвестно какую меру принимает метод в качестве аргумента - dp(нет),процент(только в XML),или что-либо другое?

Пример:

View,которая будет анимироватся:

```
<ImageView
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="10dp"
      android:id="@+id/line"
/>
```

ее аниматор:

```
 ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f,-45f);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(4000l);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(null);


    line.setPivotX(100f);
    line.setPivotY(0f);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            line.setRotation((Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
```

line.setPivotX() с значением 100 дальше (правее) чем само окончание view,которая 100dp в ширину. Значение 75 для setPivotX() совпадает с крайней правой точкой view,но откуда оно тогда взялось и как его расчитать самому?

Comment: Скорее всего значение в пикселях

Comment: Pivot всегда обозначаеться в процентах, значение принимает от 0 до 1, 0% и 100% соответственно, можно даже сказать что значение 75 и 1 будет давать один и тот же результат, вот если уже 0.99, тогда другой.

Comment: @WanSpi А можно ссылку на ресурс? (на оф.сайте такого не нашел) Потому что у меня совершенно разные результаты выполнения анимации при точке в 1,75 и 100 для метода. При 100 точка уходит за грани view на ~15% - в такой ситуации можно подумать что точка учитывает родительские границы,но родитель и эта view одинаковы по ширине и высоте. При этом всем view _width = 100dp - точка не должна уходить  за ее границы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PivotX задает позицию в пикселях. По дефолту это центр View.
[image: View source code][image: View source code]

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java

Comment: Да-да,я же говорил. Уже нашел конвертер.Только в том коде ни слова о использовании пикселей не нашел